# Libraries for WebSockets in Lisp and Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp

Which regularly maintained and stable libraries are available for hosting a WebSocket server using Common Lisp or Scheme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Common Lisp wiki, cliki, links to [two WebSocket libraries](http://www.cliki.net/WebSocket%20server), both of which are available through [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/). You should evaluate both of them and see which meets your needs. (**Edit**: [clws](https://github.com/3b/clws) appears to be the more actively maintained of the two.)

Answer (score 5):

[Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) has a WebSocket library: http://docs.racket-lang.org/net/websocket.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's the [cl-websocket](https://github.com/spratt/cl-websocket) library for Common Lisp.

Comment: That library is extremely incomplete.There are more fleshed-out implementations of WebSockets available for Common Lisp (see my answer).